# Mqtt "Software caused connection abort" error

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, mqtt, nodemcu, esp32

I am trying to send data from nodemcu(esp32) to raspberry pi using mqtt. After connecting Wifi network this error occurs. Error : Attempting MQTT connection...[E][WiFiClient.cpp:365] write(): fail on fd 55, errno: 113, "Software caused connection abort"
failed, rc=-4 try again in 5 seconds

Nodemcu fails to connect to mosquitto mqtt broker running on raspberry pi. I have tried checking whether the 1883 port is open or if there is any issues on rpi mqtt broker. Found no issues there. Tried multiple libraries. But the result remains same.
This is the code that Iam using :

```
#include "EspMQTTClient.h"

EspMQTTClient client(
  "XXXXX",
  "XXXXX",
  "XXXXXX",  // MQTT Broker server ip
     // Can be omitted if not needed
     // Can be omitted if not needed
  "TestClient",     // Client name that uniquely identify your device
  1883              // The MQTT port, default to 1883. this line can be omitted
);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Optionnal functionnalities of EspMQTTClient : 
  client.enableDebuggingMessages(); // Enable debugging messages sent to serial output
  client.enableHTTPWebUpdater(); // Enable the web updater. User and password default to values of MQTTUsername and MQTTPassword. These can be overrited with enableHTTPWebUpdater("user", "password").
  client.enableLastWillMessage("TestClient/lastwill", "I am going offline");  // You can activate the retain flag by setting the third parameter to true
}

// This function is called once everything is connected (Wifi and MQTT)
// WARNING : YOU MUST IMPLEMENT IT IF YOU USE EspMQTTClient
void onConnectionEstablished()
{
  // Subscribe to "mytopic/test" and display received message to Serial
  client.subscribe("refrigerator/temp", [](const String & payload) {
    Serial.println(payload);
  });

  // Publish a message to "mytopic/test"
  client.publish("refrigerator/temp", "Temp=34"); // You can activate the retain flag by setting the third parameter to true

  // Execute delayed instructions
  client.executeDelayed(5 * 1000, []() {
    client.publish("refrigerator/temp", "Temp=23");
  });
}

void loop()
{
  client.loop();
}
```

Comment: did you try to connect with a public mqtt server?

Comment: Actually problem solved . And I did it with MQTT server on rpi . I guess it's not public . So when these devices are in same network they are connecting and sending data but when in different network they are giving the error I mentioned above . Anyway thanks for your query @Tarick Welling .. that's where I had the issue.